# Why is my dataTables feature elements not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using datatables to paginate my table. The data from the table comes form a my server-side.
The data are seen in the table however the message **"No data available in table"** shows in the table.

[Click here for picture reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAjor.png)

Also, when I try the search feature and length change feature of the datatable, the data will suddenly disappear.

Here is my html table:

```
        <table class="table table-striped" id="executives">
            <thead>
                <th>Employee Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="color:black;"id="empTable">               
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is my dataTable:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#executives').DataTable({
                "paging": "full",
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, "All"],
                "dom": '<"my-wrapper"<"inner-wrapper"<"my-inner0"f><"my-inner1"l><"my-inner1"p>><t><"outer-wrapper"<"my-inner2"i><"my-inner1"p>>">'
            });
        });
        </script>
```

And here is my javascript file that is used to get the data from the server-side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("URL",function(data){
    var empData = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      empData.push ("<tr>");
      empData.push ("<td id=''"+ key +"''>" + value.empId + "</td>");
      empData.push ("<td id=''"+ key +"''>" + value.firstName + "</td>");
      empData.push ("<td id=''"+ key +"''>" + value.work.department + "</td>");
      empData.push ("<td id=''"+ key +"''>" + value.work.position + "</td>");
      empData.push ("<td id=''"+ key +"''>" + value.work.position + "</td>");
      empData.push ("</tr>")
      
    }); 
      $('#empTable').append(empData);
    console.log(empData);
  });
});
```

Comment: When you use `$('#empTable').append(empData);`, you are adding your data to the HTML table - where you can see it, displayed in your browser. But your `DataTable` object does not know anything about this data. That is why DataTables displays the "no data" message, and why the data in your HTML table disappears when you ask DataTables to perform any action: DataTables re-displays its data - which is no data at all.

Comment: There are various ways around this. For example, don't build strings of HTML, but instead use the DataTables built-in support for [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/) to provide the data directly to DataTables.

Comment: @andrewjames is there any other way besides using the built-in support for ajax?

Comment: @andrewjames I tried to use the built-in for ajax, however, it only shows loading in the table

Comment: _Loading_ message: That usually means there was an error - which is reported in the browser's console (typically, you can use F12 to open the console). If you share that error, and your JSON data sent from the server, we can try to troubleshoot.

Comment: _Any other way_: Yes - there are various other ways - for example, using [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()). There is also `rows.add()`. I never use those ways, myself. There are probably even more ways I don't know about...

Comment: @andrewjames yes there is actually a message in the console saying that says "Cannot read property" length" of undefined ".

Comment: This typically means DataTables cannot locate the JSON data it needs to build each row of table data. To troubleshoot that we need to see (a) your updated DataTable definition and (b) your JSON data (the data returned from the ajax call).